# How to return a random value within a range, from a Map with Integer and List of Longs in Java

Tags: java, arrays, list, dictionary, arraylist

I am trying to find a way to get a random value from a provided list of different ranges using `ThreadLocalRandom`, and return that one random value from a method. I've been trying different approaches, and not having much luck.

I've tried this:

```
private static final Long[][] values = {
    { 233L, 333L },
    { 377L, 477L },
    { 610L, 710L }
};
// This isn't correct
long randomValue = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextLong(values[0][0]);
```

But I could not figure out how to get a random value out of it for a specific range, so thought I'd try the `Map` approach, I tried creating a Map of Integers and List of Longs:

```
private static Map<Integer, List<Long>> mapValues = new HashMap<>();

{{233L, 333L}, {377L, 477L}, {610L, 710L}} // ranges I want
```

I am not sure how to store those value ranges into the Map.

I've tried adding in values, for example:

```
// Need to get the other value for the range in here, in this case 333L
map.put(1, 233L);
```

I am not sure how to add the 333L to the List, I have searched and tried various things but always get errors, such as: found 'long', required List

I want the Integer in the Map to be an id for the associated range, for example, 1 for 233L-333L, so that I can tell it first, get a random Int key from the Map, for example 1, and then use `ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextLong(origin, bound)` where origin would be 233L and bound would be 333L, and then return a random value within that range of 233L-333L.

I am not sure if this is possible, or I am simply approaching this the wrong way - any guidance/help is appreciated!

Comment: Are there always only two elements in the list representing the range? If so, wouldn't `origin = longs[0]` and `bound = longs[1]`?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Why don't you give it a try? Note however that if your ranges don't have the same size, this won't give you a uniform distribution across all the numbers. Also note that an array if basically a map were the indices are the keys: values[0] is equivalent to mapValues.get(0)

Comment: Thanks! I have tried, i think my main issue is i simply cannot figure out how to add the values into the Map - edited the question for some clarity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty straightforward. Your `long[][]` will do fine.

First, select a random index, then select a long between `values[index][0]` and `values[index][1]`<sup>1</sup>.

```
long[][] values = {
    { 233L, 333L },
    { 377L, 477L },
    { 610L, 710L }
};

// Select a random index
int index = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, values.length);

// Determine lower and upper bounds
long min = values[index][0];
long max = values[index][1];
long rnd = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextLong(min, max);
```

Of course, you could also [abstract it away](https://ideone.com/txQWDX) into some convenient classes.

Note that, for the distribution of values to be even, all ranges must have the same size (which seem to be the case in your code).

#### Implementation with even distribution

However, if you want to support different ranges while the distribution has to remain even, another approach is required.

We could calculate *a single* random number with as upper bound the total number of possible values. Then we could check in which 'bucket' the value is to be retrieved.

[Here is a working example](https://ideone.com/pjm5s6). In order to test the distribution which is said to be even, a random number is generated a million times. As you can see, each value occurs approximately 200,000 times.

---

<sup>1 In my examples, the upper bound is *exclusive*. This is consistent with many methods from the Java standard libraries, like `ThreadLocalRandom.nextLong(origin, bound)` or `LongStream.range(long start, long end)`.</sup>

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense! Thank you! And I could have all that within a method, and in this example the method would return rnd?

Comment: Exactly. You could also put this code into some convenient class. (See link in post.)

Comment: But remember: unless all ranges are equal of size, this won't provide an even distribution across all values, as JB Nizet already mentioned.

Comment: Wow, this is awesome - I really appreciate it! Very clear. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

```
int range = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(3);
long randomValue = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextLong(values[range][0],values[range][1]);
```

this will work with the array solution you tried first. first you select the range then you get the random value.

Comment: Dang, thank you! Could I then just return randomValue from a method?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest is the most straight forward.

```java
   private static final long[][] values = { { 233L, 333L
         }, { 377L, 477L
         }, { 610L, 710L
         }
   };

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      for (long v[] : values) {
         long low = v[0];
         long high = v[1];
         System.out.println("Between " + low + " and " + high + " -> "
               + getRandom(low, high));
      }
   }

   public static long getRandom(long low, long high) {
      // add 1 to high to make range inclusive
      return ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextLong(low, high + 1);
   }
```